# Determine signing certificate from an APK

Tags: android, eclipse, ssl, apk, rsa

I have created a signed APK from Eclipse for Android. I want to know that which RSA certificate type is used in that signed APK like RSA-1024 or RSA 2048.

How would i know that from APK file?

**EDIT** Title changed from "Which RSA certificate is used in signed APK in Eclipse? How to know RSA key size (1024/2048)?"

Comment: Why do you need to know that? Also why don't you just search the Android developer website instead of asking a question here?

Comment: We are developing apps in android native and Action Script.. We are getting error of Open SSL from Google. In Action Script we have select one option of RSA certificate. So we want to know that which certificate is used in android native.Thank you. :)

Comment: You generate the certificate which includes a keypair yourself as per instructions on Android site. So you should know the answer.

Comment: "...like RSA-1024 or RSA 2048" - because Android docs on [Signing Your Application](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) state the certificate should be good until 2033, you should be using a 3072-bit key. 1024-bit is definitely out of the question.

Answer (score 12):

> Which RSA certificate is used in signed APK in Eclipse?

Under Eclipse during debugging (and in the absence of another key), you will sign with the default Android debug key.

Eclipse creates it if its not present. The key is added to `debug.keystore`, with a store *and* key password of *android*. See *Signing in Debug Mode* at Android's [Signing Your Application](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode).

---

You can sign with a few tools, including `keytool` or `jarsigner`. But I believe you need to use another tool to examine the certificate in the APK.

You can use OpenSSL to dump the relevant bits since its PKCS #7, but you need manually extract the relevant files from the APK.

---

For signing, I use `jarsigner` when working from the command line. For example, on Windows with the Debug key:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore \
    -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg SHA1 \
    -sigalg SHA1withRSA <package name>.apk androiddebugkey
```

Eclipse performs similar for you under the IDE.

---

You *can't* use `jarsigner` to dump the information. For example, the following *will* print the distinguished name, but it *will not* print the `subjectPublicKeyInfo` block:

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -certs -verify Test.apk
```

Similarly, you *can't* use `keytool` because it does not print the `subjectPublicKeyInfo` block either:

```
$ keytool -printcert -file META-INF/CERT.RSA
```

---

To determine the certificate in the APK, you need to look at a couple of files. The files of interest are in the `META_INF` directory of the APK. The signatures are in an `.SF` file along with a `.RSA` file (or `.DSA` file) for each signer. The signer's `.RSA` file (or `.DSA` file) are just PKCS #7 format.

I say "the signatures are in..." because individual elements of the APK are signed, and not the entire APK. So `classes.dex` gets signed, `AndroidManifest.xml` gets signed, each icon in `res/` gets signed, etc.

Note: while `jarsigner` supports multiple signatures, Android only supports one signer (if I recall correctly).

---

Here's an example with an APK called CrackMe.apk using OpenSSL.

```
$ mkdir APK-test
$ mv CrackMe.apk APK-test
$ cd APK-test
```

Next unpack the APK. Its just a ZIP file with additional metadata in `META-INF/`.

```
$ unzip -a CrackMe.apk 
$ ls
AndroidManifest.xml    META-INF             res
CrackMe.apk            classes.dex          resources.arsc
```

Next, take a look in the `META-INF` directory.

```
$ cd META-INF/
$ ls
CERT.RSA    CERT.SF    MANIFEST.MF
```

The signatures are in `CERT.SF`, and the signer is in `CERT.RSA`.

Finally, use OpenSSL to parse `CERT.RSA`.

```
$ openssl pkcs7 -in CERT.RSA -inform DER -print_certs | openssl x509 -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1346030704 (0x503acc70)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=NY, L=New York, O=Unknown, OU=Unknown, CN=Example, LLC
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug 27 01:25:04 2012 GMT
            Not After : Dec  5 01:25:04 2035 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=NY, L=New York, O=Unknown, OU=Unknown, CN=Example, LLC
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (3072 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:8d:a8:9a:34:84:d5:72:4f:e8:e7:69:78:e4:17:
                    13:93:e8:c5:23:a0:93:a7:f8:6c:58:3d:f0:ed:30:
                    ...
                    c1:2d:5e:9f:a4:79:56:19:7d:26:4d:27:6a:3e:26:
                    c0:fd:6a:ed:24:e9:62:80:73:8d
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         80:c0:ac:a5:65:13:f3:2d:dd:d5:71:82:7c:2e:72:63:72:cf:
         76:49:4b:09:3c:12:e7:d6:9b:3d:53:8b:d4:e0:9c:ff:f2:d6:
         ...
         80:4d:9b:15:3f:82:1a:72:b2:4b:fd:05:2b:e7:36:f0:43:98:
         80:b7:8f:6c:fd:64
```

You can also use `-pubkey` when utilizing `x509` to extract the public key PEM format:

```
$ openssl pkcs7 -in CERT.RSA -inform DER -print_certs | openssl x509 -noout -pubkey 
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

---

If interested in the Android APK validation code, see [`collectCertificates`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java#568) from `PackageParser.java`.