# Sign .APK to avoid Google server error, after download from Test-Fairy

Tags: android, google-api, apk, jarsigner, zipalign

I am using this testing tool, **Test-Fairy**. The way it works is: I upload an .apk, they make some changes and then they ask to download the .apk file back and sign myself (to support my own key and be aligned with google play services). To do this, i am doing the usual:

**jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore debugkey.keystore App.apk android**

And then **zipalign -f -v 4 App.apk App_Aligned.apk**

After this, my app is not working properly when i go to an activity with google maps, even when my debug SHA1 key is added to google services console. When i install the app from Eclipse, google maps and all google related services are working just fine.

Anyone has a clue why is this happening? Am i missing any step?

NOTES:

- I tried to use jarsinger from JDK 1.7 and then from JDK 1.6, none of them worked.
- I tried to sign also with the release.keystore i use to sign from Eclipse to generate the Production .apk, which generated this way is also working perfect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine signing certificate from an APK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24217571/608639). The answers include the steps to sign an APK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work for TestFairy :)

Your own answer is correct too. When using TestFairy/Android, you have two options:

One, is to use the web-upload, and then we create a unique certificate for your APK. We must re-sign because we do minor changes (like change the AndroidManifest file, and automatically add our SDK.) When using this method, you will see the new SHA1 and MD5 in the Build Settings page. There is also an explanation in the docs how to use Google Maps.

Second, is to use one of our uploaders: command line, gradle or jenkins. These tools (with configuration) will use your local keystore, so you retain the same signature as the output from the compiler. This method is recommended as it will also allow your users to upgrade from a non-testfairy build to a testfairy-enabled build.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was simple.

In Test-Fairy, inside the Project settings, there is a SHA1 (created by them) that i needed to add to Google API Developers Console, together with the other SHA1 debug keys.

Now it works like a charm.