# How to get app signing time based on APK file

Tags: android, python, security, reverse-engineering

I am working on a project that analyzing APK files for detecting malware apps, and I wonder how to extract the SIGNING TIME rather than PACKAGING TIME. This is one feature I read from a paper and it seems surprising useful.

Comment: [Determine signing certificate from an APK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24225807/608639). Once you have the certificate, I believe you can do things like extract the time.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three ways I know of to get something like the signing time. There first is to use `keytool`:

```
$ keytool -printcert -jarfile sample.apk
Signer #1:

Signature:

Owner: CN=GService inc, OU=G Service inc, O=G, L=New York, ST=New York, C=US
Issuer: CN=GService inc, OU=G Service inc, O=G, L=New York, ST=New York, C=US
Serial number: 6f30f864
Valid from: Thu Dec 17 04:12:27 PST 2015 until: Wed Dec 12 04:12:27 PST 2035
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  4D:36:65:14:59:5B:74:8F:2C:9D:92:30:F6:1D:90:8A
     SHA1: A8:85:7B:72:4C:EE:55:83:09:D5:AC:5D:1A:02:80:C5:F6:83:2B:40
     SHA256: 04:A7:24:9F:35:D5:8D:7E:F6:0F:73:81:35:5D:23:16:0D:FC:EA:61:C4:15:61:CC:06:8D:36:D9:C6:55:12:B7
     Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: C1 C5 19 32 72 47 46 C5   01 CC 4B AF 12 40 3D D2  ...2rGF...K..@=.
0010: B5 52 45 5E                                        .RE^
]
]
```

This gets you the likely time the certificate was created: `Thu Dec 17 04:12:27 PST 2015`.

The second is to use `jarsigner`:

```
$ jarsigner -verify -verbose sample.apk

sm      4284 Wed Apr 13 11:03:18 PDT 2016 AndroidManifest.xml
sm      9193 Wed Apr 13 11:03:18 PDT 2016 res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
sm      5057 Wed Apr 13 11:03:18 PDT 2016 res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
sm     14068 Wed Apr 13 11:03:18 PDT 2016 res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png
sm      1408 Wed Apr 13 11:03:18 PDT 2016 resources.arsc
sm     20388 Wed Apr 13 11:03:18 PDT 2016 classes.dex
s        523 Wed Apr 13 11:03:18 PDT 2016 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
         576 Wed Apr 13 11:03:18 PDT 2016 META-INF/CERT.SF
        1368 Wed Apr 13 11:03:18 PDT 2016 META-INF/CERT.RSA

  s = signature was verified
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope
```

This gets you what appears to be the last modified times of all the entries in the APK. They're all the same in this APK, but they're sometimes different. All the last modified times probably have to be greater than the "valid from" date.

The third option is programmatically using `JarFile` in Java:

```
private static void printCertInfo(String jarPath) throws Exception {
    // verify = true is key here
    JarFile apkFile = new JarFile(jarPath, true);
    JarEntry androidManifestEntry = apkFile.getJarEntry("AndroidManifest.xml");
    if (androidManifestEntry == null) {
        System.err.println("APK has no AndroidManifest.xml");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    // Need to fully read stream to verify cert
    System.out.println("Android manifest probably signed: " + androidManifestEntry.getLastModifiedTime());

    ByteStreams.copy(apkFile.getInputStream(androidManifestEntry), ByteStreams.nullOutputStream());
    // Assuming only signed with a single cert (not always true, but you get the idea)
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) androidManifestEntry.getCertificates()[0];
    System.out.println("Android manifest cert probably created: " + cert.getNotBefore());
    System.out.println("Full cert: " + cert.toString());
}
```

You might think you could use `androidManifestEntry.getCodeSigners()[0].getTimestamp()` but it's always `null` and I'm not sure what it is. The above code gives this output:

```
Android manifest probably signed: 2016-04-13T18:03:18Z
Android manifest cert probably created: Thu Dec 17 04:12:27 PST 2015
Full cert: [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GService inc, OU=G Service inc, O=G, L=New York, ST=New York, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  // ** SNIP -- you get the idea **
```