# How to get signature from this APK?

Tags: java, android, apk, keytool

Recently I met a weird apk. I can only get its correct signature MD5 with keytool on ubuntu with jdk-1.8

Keytool on windows/osx/debian/centos doesn't work and shows input error.

Openssl can convert the .RSA to PEM but the MD5 is not right (compare with the value from Android API).

I also tried APK-Parser even apk-sig. Both of them cannot parse it.

Anyone could tell me what's the problem?

[original apk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6vxrq2lrd9xse9s/com.chuangguansha.cgs2.apk?dl=0)

[.RSA from apk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3wb7g50jw7yod9e/CERT.RSA?dl=0)
[image]

Comment: Also see [Determine signing certificate from an APK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24225807/608639)